# What is the best way to use ListView and GroupBoxes as an "options" window?

Tags: c#, user-interface

What is the best way to use ListView and a set of GroupBoxes as an Options window?

For example, Listview will have items such as General, Sounds, Shortcuts and there will be three groupboxes defining those same things.

What would be the best programmatical way to navigate through them everytime an item in the listview is selected?

Hide all groupboxes, then show groupbox based by index of selected listview? Or does anyone have a better idea to handle something like this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a better way, but in the past that what you described is the general approach I have taken.

Answer (score 2):

I may have misunderestimated your question, but perhaps a TreeView would be more appropriate for your problem?  This would allow you to have top-level category nodes (like General, Sounds etc.) and then lists of items under each node.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using a TabControl if there isn't too many categories in options. This way all hide/show mechanics will be handled by it.